# How to create hyperlink within PDF (which is opened in browser) which will open in a new tab/window

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I generate some PDF via XSLT transformation (FOP) from XML. The PDF file is opened in the browser. If it contains any hyperlink, that hyperlink is supposed to open in a new browser tab/window. I'm quite not sure if it is even possible. Any insights?

Comment: As you can see at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-show-destination there is no solution since apparently "Adobe's browser plugin, for example, ignores the /NewWindow flag."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [show-destination](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_show-destination.asp) property. It's mentioned [on some sites](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf4-extension.htm#IDA2CUQ) but I couldn't get it to work. I believe it also depends on which Fo Processor you're using, your browser settings and the PDF reader.

Comment: Yep, I found that too. We use Apache FOP which is apparently still not compliant with show-destination property. According to http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html#fo-property-show-destination there is another problem inside Adobe's browser plugin.

I guess I will have to explain it to the customer :)

Comment: (1) `show-destination` is defined by XSL 1.1: https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#show-destination. (2) FWIW, AH Formatter supports it: https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-fo11.html#show-destination